# Count how many times a table name appears in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find how many times a table name appears in a list of stored procedures. Is there an easy way to do this?

The result should be like

```
Sproc name       count of tablename
abc                  5
def                  3
ghi                  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer :) by a little try! Thanks. Just in case if someone needs:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id), count(text)
FROM syscomments 
WHERE 
[text] like '%AccountAttributes%'
AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
and OBJECT_NAME(id) in (
 'sproc_name','sproc_name1'
)
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

Comment: Not a problem I've ever had to solve, but that's a pretty elegant solution.  Thanks for sharing it back to the group.